# Parse JSON(with subJson) without java subobjects

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, jsonpath

How i can parse json string like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}
```

But, from **"address"** i need only **"city"**. How i can make it without creating new class (for lib. GSON)?
I try use JsonPath,  but i cant understand how replace JsonObject "address" to String value "city".

Comment: Can you please clarify your question i am little bit confused :), You only need `city` from `address` or want to replace the complete `address` object with `city` ??

Comment: you don't need to replace the string address with the city. You just need to parse the JSON tree structure

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh i find easy way for parse all json, but i dont need all values from "address". i need only "firstName", "lastName", "age" and "city"

Comment: yes for city you first have to point till address and within address object you will find the city field

Comment: try this : JsonPath.read(document, "$.address.city"); Please refer the following link for more details. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Can you show us what exactly you are trying and what is going wrong?

Comment: @akshayapandey but how i can get other values? i need vall values on single class

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh from json in question i need POJO with values "firstName", "lastName", "age" and "city". i search easy way for this operation.

Comment: refer the following link for serializing and deserializing using Gson. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization

Comment: I dont think you can bypass the structure of json and directly get the things easily, You have to create the structure as its nested and then only it will get handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject address=jsonObject.getJSONObject("address");
        String city=address.getString("city");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yes) i know i can make like this) but with lib. GSON i can make it easier. but for GSON i need create new POJO, i dont want it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.parse("your-json-here");
YourPojoHere pojo = new YourPojoHere(
   ctx.read("$.firstName"),
   ctx.read("$.lastName"),
   ctx.read("$.age"),
   ctx.read("$.address.city"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I understood your question correct: you want to replace `/address` with `/address/city`, so that

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  }
}
```

would then be

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : "Nara"
}
```

---

**Option A**: You could use [it.bewares JSON](https://gitlab.com/it-bewares-json/json), then using JSON Selectors it would be simply:

```
JSONFactory JSON = new JSONFactory(SimpleJSONParser.class, SimpleJSONGnerator.class);

String input = "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"doe\",\"age\":26,\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"naist street\",\"city\":\"Nara\",\"postalCode\":\"630-0192\"}}";
JSONValue json = JSON.parse(input);

json.put("address", JSON.find(new JSONSelector(".\"address\".\"city\"")))
```

You could use Dependecy Injection for the JSONFactory:

```
@Inject
JSONFactory JSON;
```

---

**Option B**: Instead you could use in combination with [it.bewares JSON](https://gitlab.com/it-bewares-json/json) also [it.bewares JSONPatch](https://gitlab.com/it-bewares-json/json). JSON Patch is a proposed standard (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Patch), [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902))

A valid JSON Patch would be:

```
[
  { "op": "move", "from": "/address/city", "path": "/address" }
]
```

Using it.bewares JSONPatch it would be:

```
JSONFactory JSON = new JSONFactory(SimpleJSONParser.class, SimpleJSONGnerator.class);

String input = "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"doe\",\"age\":26,\"address\":{\"streetAddress\":\"naist street\",\"city\":\"Nara\",\"postalCode\":\"630-0192\"}}";
JSONValue json = JSON.parse(input);

String patchString = "[{\"op\":\"move\",\"from\":\"/address/city\",\"path\":\"/address\"}]";
JSONPatch patch = new JSONPatch(JSONArray<JSONObject<JSONString>> JSON.parse(patchString));
JSONPatch.execute(patch, json);
```